# Singleton in multithreaded without using synchronized keyword

Tags: java, singleton

Can any one explain how below code would work fine in multithreaded environment especially when it is not using synchronized keyword?

```
public class Singleton {
private Singleton() {}

private static class SingletonHolder { 
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
}

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
}
}
```

Comment: @leppie, that seems a little ... harsh, especially for a relative newbie (though I don't deny you the right to do it, our votes are ours to do as we see fit - "I don't agree with what you say but I'll fight to the death your right to say it" and all that jazz). I see the votes as applying to the Q/As themselves, not as some sort of reward/punishment mechanism for the people posting them. Since you actually _fixed_ the problem yourself by adding the tag, the question can't be considered deficient. IMOBIBWBJAMW (in my opinion but I've been wrong before - just ask my wife) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsynchronised singletons can work just fine in threaded environments provided they're instantiated in one thread before other threads attempt to use them.

This may be as simple as calling `getInstance()` from the main thread before starting up any of those other threads.

However, that's irrelevant in this particular case. Since your instance variable is `static final`, this means it will be constructed when the class is initially loaded. By calling `getInstance()`, the classloaders brings in the class and, as part of that, constructs the `INSTANCE` member before allowing the call through to `getInstance()` to proceed.

The classloader itself has locking mechanisms to prevent concurrent execution by multiple threads and therefore all calls to `getInstance()` (including the first, immediately following the loading of the class) will return the already-initialised value.

Comment: When multiple threads are trying to call Signleton.getInstance(), the above code provides unique instance without sharing that instance with each other. Now, I wanna know how exactly it happens when there is no synchronized keyword? Because even multiple threads can call SingletonHolder at exact same time, then how come there won't be any synchronization issue here?

Comment: @Mike, they _don't_ provide unique instances. There is _one_ instance constructed very early on and each call to `getInstance` returns that one.

Comment: So, does it mean that when 2 threads will call getInstance at exact same time, it'll create different instances of them?

Comment: No, you'll get two references to the _same_ instance. Keep in mind this instance is created before main starts, and therefore before any threads are running. So, by the time any of your code is allowed to call `getInstance`, `INSTANCE` already exists.

Comment: Then, when should we use lazy instantiation using synchronized block or synchronized method as shown below? `class Singleton {
 private static Singleton uniqueInstance;

 private Singleton() { ... }

 public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
  if (uniqueInstance == null) {
   uniqueInstance = new Singleton();
  }

  return uniqueInstance;
 }
`

Comment: I personally use lazy initialisation when there's the possibility that the program may not _need_ the singleton to be instantiated. To be honest, I'm having a hard time coming up with a use case at the moment. I suppose if it depended on another class having been constructed before it, it would make sense to ensure you controlled the order of construction.

Comment: And now the "try to avoid discussion in comments" warnings have started to kick in. It may be best to ask another question re why one would do lazy instantiation rather than continue a discussion here (remember to search first in case it's already been covered).

Comment: @paxdiablo The static class definition SingletonHolder within it is not initialized until the JVM determines that HoldInstance must be executed. So, here the singleton instance is not initialized until the first call to the static instance. Here, intialization phase is taken care by JSL in serial manner, so concurrent access to static instance will not cause an issue in this case. Please refer this article for more details : https://crunchify.com/lazy-creation-of-singleton-threadsafe-instance-without-using-synchronized-keyword/

Comment: I have a question. If we had declared INSTANCE as static variable of the Singleton class (and removed the inner class), wouldnt it be thread safe? It would have initialized when loading Singleton class and would therefore be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

As for the up front initialization there is no need to use synchronized keywords because your initializing your instance statically which in almost every case is the preferred way to do it for two reasons. One you get to amortize the expensive initialization costs over the length of the application's run time and two(particularly important to you) is that it negates the need for synchronization allowing you to avoid hairy double checked locking scenarios.

If you choose to use lazy initialization then you need to ensure that the entirety of the initialization process is synchronized otherwise in multi-processor environments you run the risk of creating two singleton instances. [Double Checked Locking And Why its a problem](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html)

After intialization your code will work fine in a multi threaded environment. The caveat is that you are sharing one instance among all your threads so you need to ensure that your `INSTANCE` is thread-safe. There are two ways to do this. First, you could ensure that all you members are private and any access to methods that alter `INSTANCE's` state use the `synchronized`  or contained synchronized blocks where state modification occurs.

A second and probably better way to achieve thread safety is the initialize your instance up front and make it immutable once its initialized. Immutable objects may be shared freely among threads with no need for synchronization.Read this Java Practices article for more info on immutable objects and how to create them.

[Java Practices: Immutable objects](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29)